# Visual Studio com erro na API do Google Maps - Android 6.0 e API versão 29.0.02

Tags: android, visual-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xamarin.android

> Erros de Instalação: XA5207 Instale o pacote: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' disponível no instalador do SDK. O arquivo de biblioteca Java 'C:\Users\vinic\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.1.1.0\embedded\libs/internal_impl-23.1.1.jar' não existe.
>
> XA5207 Instale o pacote: 'GPS Basement' disponível no instalador do SDK. O arquivo de biblioteca Java 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\classes.jar' não existe.
>
> XA5207 Instale o pacote: 'GPS Base' disponível no instalador do SDK. O arquivo de biblioteca Java 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\classes.jar' não existe.

**Quando clico 2 vezes ele não está conseguindo instalar.**

Mais detalhes do erro no link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxir9wjix1mtpg5/erro%20VS.txt?dl=0

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: "Quando clico 2 vezes" não me parece uma boa descrição, coloque print do erro, ou da tela de instalação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolução do problema
alterar os arquivos .aar para .zip

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors